# Is Kafka Connect JDBC Source connector idempotent?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Reading the [documentation of this connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/index.html) there isn't a mention about this characteristic.

So, does this connector guarantee that it won't produce duplicated records under broker crashes or whatever could happen?

Do we have to configure something to get indempotence the same way we would do with [any other Kafka Producer](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html) (`enable.idempotence: true`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Connect JDBC source connector, is not idempotent at the moment. Here's the relevant [KIP-318](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-318%3A+Make+Kafka+Connect+Source+idempotent) and [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7077).